# How do i check if a webpage exists with java?

Tags: java, connection, html, forum

So here's the deal. I don't have it yet, but starting Friday, I'm in the process of making a forum. What I'd like to do is check to see if a user is registered on the forum.

I'm not sure exactly, but lets say the users are stored in URL/users/NAME.WHATEVER (jsp?)

how, in java, do i make a URL connection, and check to see if URL/users/Robert.WHATEVER == null?

Comment: If you're writing the forum, your code is responsible for producing the pages that come back when someone accesses your URLs; it doesn't make sense for the forum software to open connections to its own URLs.  Typically, a forum application stores all its information (such as users and posts) in a relational database, such as MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: I'm going to be using phpBB, I'm just setting up the forum.
The actual implementation of this is my minecraft server, if possibly, I'd like to be able to check if a user has registered on the forums, and "congratulate" them for doing so.

Comment: That would best be done within phpBB itself, as a mod or extension or something, so that it can react to the actual user registration within phpBB.  If you write a separate Java program, what would cause it to be executed, and what would tell it the username that it should look for?

Comment: When a player logs into the server it fires an "event" PlayerJoinEvent, from that even I can get the Player object, which holds the players name, i can use that name to check, and by listening to the PlayerJoinEvent I can execute the code to check if they are registered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even you could have googled your answer:
One simple way is to use the [Apache Http Components](http://hc.apache.org)

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/users/Robert.WHATEVER");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 404) {
   System.out.println("User Robert.WHATEVER not found");
}
```

There is a good [Tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/) with many examples which explains how to use the HttpClient.

Another highlevel framework is the [ResteasyClientFramework](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html).

Comment: So, this checks to see if the page exists, (if it doesn't 404 error page not found), and I can go from there. Correct?